# Почему this в onclick необязателен?

Tags: javascript, html, события

Почему в `onclick` работает `innerHTML^=1`, хотя по идее должно быть `this.innerHTML^=1`?

```css
/* ignore css */ p { float: left; font-size: 4em; width: 2em; line-height: 2em; border: 1px solid; text-align: center; margin: 0; cursor: pointer; background: silver; -webkit-user-select: none; -moz-user-select: none; -ms-user-select: none; user-select: none; } p + p { margin-left: .125em; }
```

```html
<p onclick=innerHTML^=1>0
<p onclick=this.innerHTML^=1>0
```

Comment: Что это за чехарда? Какой-то движок темплейтов? Или натурально xor? =)

Comment: Видимо, onclick выполняется в контексте `with(this)`.

Comment: @vp_arth, да, это xor :)

Comment: @vp_arth, а это где-то написано, что он `with(this)`? Вот нигде не могу найти))

Comment: `<input value=0 onclick=value++>`

Comment: HTML не определяет поведение конкретных реализаций скриптов [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html40/html40.txt):18.2.3 Intrinsic events

Comment: @vp_arth, там в примере есть this: `onchange="if (!checkNum(this.value, 1, 10))
        {this.focus();this.select();} else {thanks()}"
    VALUE="0">`

Comment: Кажется я что-то упустил в своей жизни... Где это применяется и где почитать? Дайте ссылку, пожалуйста :)

Comment: [internal raw uncompiled handler](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#internal-raw-uncompiled-handler). Там не совсем `with`

Comment: @DenisBubnov, это применяется в inline-обработчиках событий

Comment: @Grundy, Да-да-да, точно, где-то натыкался. Завтра почитаю, спасибо)

Comment: @Grundy, а кто ответ писать будет? ;)

Comment: Разве `inline`-код не оборачивается в функцию с особенностями (типа `with`)?

Comment: @Qwertiy, ну там же был ответ уже, только ссылки не хватало :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Внутренний сырой неоткомпилированный обработчик это тупль со следующей информацией:

- Неоткомпилированное тело скрипта
- Место происхождения тела скрипта, если необходимо сообщить об ошибке

Когда пользовательский агент(ПА) получает текущее значение обработчика события `H`, он должен выполнить эти шаги:

1. Если значение H – внутренний сырой неоткомпилированный обработчик, выполнить эти подшаги:

   1. Если `H` это обработчик события элемента, то пусть `element` это элемент, а `document` – Document элемента.

      Иначе, `H` это обработчик события объекта Window: пусть `element` будет null, и пусть `document` это Document, ассоциированный самым последним с этим Window-объектом.
   2. Если `document` – не в контексте браузинга, или если скриптинг включён для контекст браузинга `document`'а, тогда возвратить null и прервать алгоритм получения текущего значения обработчика события.
   3. Пусть `body` это неоткомпилированное тело скрипта во внутреннем сыром неоткомпилированном обработчике.
   4. Пусть `location` это место, из которого происходит тело скрипта, как задано внутренним сырым неоткомпилированным обработчиком.
   5. Если `element` – не null и `element` имеет владельца формы, пусть `form owner` это владелец формы. Иначе – пусть `form owner` будет null.
   6. Пусть `script settings` это объект настроек скрипта, созданный для объекта Window, с которым `document` в настоящее время ассоциирован.
   7. Получить окружение выполнения скрипта для JavaScript из `script settings`.
   8. Если `body` не разбирабельно как FunctionBody, или если при парсинге выявляется ошибка early error, тогда следовать этим подшагам:

      1. Установить H со значением null.
      2. Сообщить об ошибке для соответствующего script со соответствующей позицией (номер строки и номер столбца), заданной в `location`, используя глобальный объект, специфицированный в `script settings`, в качестве цели. Если ошибка по-прежнему не обработана после этого, тогда о ней можно сообщить пользователю.
      3. Перескочить ниже на шаг end.

      > **Примечание:**  FunctionBody определена в ECMAScript edition 5 section 13 Function Definition. Ошибка Early error определена в ECMAScript edition 5 section 16 Errors. [ECMA262]
   9. Если `body` начинается с Directive Prologue, содержащего Use Strict Directive, тогда пусть strict будет true, иначе – пусть `strict` будет false.

      > **Примечание:**  Термины "Directive Prologue" и "Use Strict Directive" определены в ECMAScript edition 5 section 14.1 Directive Prologues and the Use Strict Directive. [ECMA262]
   10. Используя окружение выполнения скрипта, полученное выше, создать объект функции (как определено в ECMAScript edition 5 section 13.2 Creating Function Objects), с:

       **Списком параметров `FormalParameterList`**

       - **Если `H` это обработчик события onerror объекта *Window*:**

         - Пусть функция имеет 5 аргументов: *event*, *source*, *lineno*, *colno* и *error*.
       - **Иначе:**

         - Пусть функция имеет один аргумент *event*.
       - **Тело функции `FunctionBody:`**

         - Результат парсинга `body` выше.
       - **Лексическое окружение `Scope`:**

         1. Пусть `Scope` это результат NewObjectEnvironment(`document`, `global environment`).
         2. Если `form owner` не null, пусть `Scope` это результат NewObjectEnvironment(`>form owner`, `Scope`).
         3. Если `element` не null, пусть `Scope` это результат NewObjectEnvironment(`element`, `Scope`).

         > **Примечание:** NewObjectEnvironment() определена в ECMAScript edition 5 section 10.2.2.3 NewObjectEnvironment (O, E). [ECMA262]
       - **Булев флаг `Strict`**

         - Значение `strict`.
       - Пусть `function` это данная новая функция.
   11. Пусть `script` это новый скрипт.
   12. Пусть кодовой точкой входа `script`'а будет `function`.
   13. Пусть объектом настроек `script`'а будет `script settings`.
   14. Установить `H` в `function`.
2. *End*: Возвратить значение H.

Comment: @Grundy, перелогиньтесь.

Comment: @Other, не, я бы по другому перевел :-)

Comment: @Grundy, думаю вообще бы не перевели - копипаста и разбирайся сам :)

Comment: @Other, не правда :-) посмотри, у меня в ответах есть упоминания спецификации с переводом :)

Comment: @Grundy, once in the blue moon...

Comment: В каком пункте описано поведение из вопроса? Вот это: `NewObjectEnvironment(element, Scope)`?

Comment: @vp_arth, https://people-mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es5.1-final.html#sec-10.2.2.3

Answer (score 3):

Если коротко и на пальцах, то при использовании инлайн-обработчиков неявно генерируется примерно такой код:

```
with(document)
with(currentElement.form)
with(currentElement)
currentElement.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
   // Тут содержимое атрибута onclick
})
```

Более формальный алгоритм можно будет увидеть по ссылке, которую привел Grundy:
https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#internal-raw-uncompiled-handler

Answer (score 2):

В поддержку своей версии о том, что атрибуты onxxxx выполняются примерно как `with (this) eval(script)` привожу сниппет:

```js
  var el = document.createElement('P');
  el.a='Ok';
  el.setAttribute('onclick', 'console.info(a, this.a)');
  el.click();
```

Как видим, это работает даже с только что созданным свойством.

Почему и где найти спецификацию к этому не знаю.
Также не исключаю, что это работает не во всех браузерах.

Comment: Мой вариант работает в FF, Chrome, IE 11, Oper 12. Этот не проверял, но думаю, что получится то же самое. Мне интереснее, где именно написано, что оно должно работать :)

Comment: В отличии от eval инлайн-обработчики компилируются.