# Не срабатывает обработчик событий JS

Tags: javascript, html

По событию должна происходить смена классов. Скрипт подключаю извне, в теге head. В консоли ничего не происходит.

```js
function click() {

  document.getElementById("svg_1").classList.add("nav-icon--active");
  document.getElementById("nav_link_1").classList.add("nav-item-link--active");

}
```

```html
<li class="nav-item" onclick="click(this)">
  <svg class="nav-icon" viewBox="0 0 15.07 15" id="svg_1">
           <path class="cls-1" d="M7.51,8.06a4,4,0,1,0-4-4A4,4,0,0,0,7.51,8.06Zm0-7a3,3,0,1,1-3,3A3,3,0,0,1,7.51,1.05Z"/>
           <path class="cls-1" d="M.53,15h14a.53.53,0,0,0,.53-.53A5.07,5.07,0,0,0,10,9.41h-5A5.07, 5.07,0,0,0,0,14.47.53.53,0,0,0,.53,15Zm4.53-4.53h5a4,4,0,0,1,4,3.47H1.1A4,4,0,0,1,5.06,10.47Z"/>
      </svg>
  <a href="#" class="nav-item-link" id="nav_link_1">Профиль</a>
</li>
```

Comment: Так а событие должно быть при нажатии конкретно на что?

Comment: работает, если изменить название функции

Comment: связанный вопрос (наверное): https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/624717/178988