# Разный контекст при разном навешивании обработчика событий

Tags: javascript, html

Почему обработка события через JS работает как надо, а через html, this ссылается на window
Есть такая функция

```
function foo() {
  console.log(this)
}
```

В этом примере работает нормально

```
let btn = document.querySelector('button');
btn.onclick = foo;
```

Здесь ссылается на window

```
<button onclick="foo()">Button</button>
```

Причем так тоже работает нормально

```
<button onclick="console.log(this)">Button</button>
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/624717/178988

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**this** - контекст вызова функции, если кратко, то содержимое фигурных скобок {} выше тела функции.

Теперь посмотрим что получается у вас:

```
function foo() {
  console.log(this)
}
```

Если просто вызвать foo() то вы увидите window, так функция объявлена, по сути, в глобальной области видимости или в window

Если сделать так:

```
const newContext = {
  fn: foo
}
newContext.fn();
```

то вы увидите объект **newContext**

А теперь посмотрим на регистрацию событий нажатия кнопки(click):

```
<button onclick="foo()">Button1</button>
```

Тут **this** берется из окружения, где объявлена функция(здесь она будет только вызываться)
А вот здесь:

```
let btn = document.getElementById("btn");
btn.onclick = foo;
```

**this** это объект **btn** - по аналогии с **newContext**

---

Если вам очень хочется указывать обработчик события из HTML, то можно сделать так:

```js
function foo2(self) {
    console.log(self)
}
```

```html
<button onclick="foo2(this)">Button</button>
```

Comment: В средней части ответа какой-то бред...

Comment: @Qwertiy Да... поправил. Надо что тли сесть и пару сотен эссе написать, что бы более правильнее формулировать мысли )

Comment: _"Тут this берется из окружения, где объявлена функция(здесь она будет только вызываться)"_ - я не понимаю смысл этой фразы. А в _"this это объект btn - по аналогии с newContext"_ и аналогия кривая, и вообще, не в том дело, как оно присваивается.

Answer (score 0):

Ознакомьтесь с this и областью видимости. this — это уникальная переменная, которая хранит в себе контекст исполняемого кода. Контекст this меняется в зависимости от его использования.

И почему бы вам просто не вызывать функцию сразу, не делая лишних переменных:

```
function foo() {
  console.log('Что-то')
}
```

```
<button onclick="foo()">Button</button>
```

[Статья на habr по this](https://habr.com/ru/companies/ruvds/articles/419371/) - советую ознакомиться, удачи !)

Comment: Да, натыкался на эти статьи. Эту тему изучал ранее, и по отдельности все понятно. Но все равно, ну никак не могу уловить связь.

И насчет лишних переменных. Да, вы правы. У меня несколько кнопок, и в зависимости от нажатой кнопки, ее текст меняется.
Чтобы для каждой не создавать переменную
`
let btn1 = document.querySelector('.btn1');
btn1.onclick = foo;
let btn2 = ...
`
хотел добавить функцию через html атрибут. Но так не срабатывает

Comment: Этот ответ вообще никак не связан с вопросом. Да и что-то совет какой-то непонятный.

Answer (score 0):

Потому что текст обработчика - это код функции, которая вызывается с неким this.

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('button').onclick)
```

```html
<button onclick="console.log(this)">Button</button>
```

Когда ты пишешь вызов функции, это всего лишь стейтемент в коде другой функции, а вызов `foo()`, очевидно, происходит с контекстом window или undefined.

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('button').onclick)
```

```html
<script>function foo() { console.log(this === window) }</script>
<button onclick="foo()">Button</button>
```

Когда ты присваиваешь функцию в коде, ты присваиваешь саму функцию, а не создаёшь тело функции:

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('button')
btn.onclick = foo
console.log(btn.onclick)
```

```html
<script>function foo() { console.log(this === window || this) }</script>
<button>Button</button>
```